# How to create keyboard shortcut that toggle start/stop .jar file?

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, java, shortcuts

*# this is for running the AIORemote server from my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Laptop to run with my Android device as remote control mouse pad and wireless file transfer.*

I know how to create keyboard shortcut which execute .jar file but i'd like to know how to make a shortcut that would toggle (start/stop) the program either with .jar or .sh files provided by the program developer.

On the same note, is there any way that I can edit the Keyboard Shortcut message that pops up on pressing the "Super" key? I am not sure if this make any more sense but I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit with 3.13 mainline kernel.

Comment: This is certainly possible. The only way to kill the java program would be with something like `kill` though.

Comment: is that how the scripting behind 'toggle' feature are written?

Comment: Toggle features? If you mean like settings within Ubuntu, no, it's a bit more complicated than that.

Comment: I figured I'd put the actual command here, it's `killall -STOP java` to freeze the process and `killall -CONT java` to resume it. You could also use `kill` if you knew the process ID. Not sure how to toggle it, though, and I doubt that that's the answer you're looking for. How do you terminate the server? Is it a GUI or a CLI app?